# Difference between render(url('url_name')) and render(controller('controller_name')?

Tags: symfony

Is there a difference between thoses 2 lignes?

```
render(url('hwi_oauth_connect'));
render(controller("HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:connect"));
```

with route being (xml):

```
hwi_oauth_connect:    
path: /login/    
defaults: {_controller: HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:connect }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not a difference.
You use [render()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#render).
In [french documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160606054206/http://documentation-symfony.fr/reference/twig_reference.html), it's all the same thing for renders the fragment for the given controller or URI:

- render(uri, options = {})
- render(controller('B:C:a', {params}))
- render(path('route', {params}))
- render(url('route', {params}))

Comment: ok because I tried both and get the same result, my html.twig form as I wanted.